# Running ActiveX page under Linux

Tags: linux, activex

I would need to run from Linux (Ubuntu 13.10) a web page that uses ActiveX framework. Can anybody  help me on this? I tried to install IE through wine, but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/Mozilla-ActiveX-Control.shtml

However the functionality will be limited.

Otherwise, failing to get IE working under wine the only other option would be a VM.

Comment: But Mozilla ActiveX Control is also only for Windows. So without VM or wine no chance. Very annoying if you think about the huge amount of devices on the market that rely on ActiveX for their Web-Interface. The big benefit of Web based applications (platform independence) is thereby turned to the opposite. For Linux users it is still important to check for no need of ActiveX before buying a device. Like in other sectors there should be a Label "Warning, for windows only!".

Comment: "Warning, for windows only!" - most products that require ActiveX do, in fact, have such a hint.